# Redirecting to success page after validation

Tags: php

I thought of using php header to redirect upon validation successful. However it's seems broken to me. How do I implement one then. Condition is when all the validation is validated then it would only redirect.

```
   <?php
         // define variables and set to empty values
         $nameErr = $lastnameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $confirmpasswordErr = $checkboxErr=  "";
         $name = $lastname = $email = $password = $confirmpassword = $checkbox = "";

         if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

            if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
               $nameErr = "First Name is required";
            }else {
               $name = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
            }

                 if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
               $lastnameErr = "Last Name is required";
            }else {
               $name = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
               $emailErr = "Email is required";
            }else {
               $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

               // check if e-mail address is well-formed
               if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
               }
            }


            if(!empty($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirmpassword"])) {
                $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
                $confirmpassword = test_input($_POST["confirmpassword"]);
                if (strlen($_POST["password"]) <= '8') {
                    $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
                }
                elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
                    $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
                }
                elseif(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password)) {
                    $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
                }
                elseif(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$password)) {
                    $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
                }
            }
            elseif(empty($_POST["password"])) {
                $passwordErr = "Password not filled at all";
            }

            elseif(!empty($_POST["password"])) {
                $confirmpasswordErr = "Password do not match";
            }

        if(!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){ 
        $checkboxErr = "Please check the checkbox";
        }
        else {
               $checkbox = test_input($_POST["checkbox"]);

            }









         }



         function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
         }
      ?>

  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: why PHP close before header.

Comment: It's just a example. I know you have to put before php tag

Answer (score 0):

Set $error = 1 if any condition get failed  , and at the bottom check if($error!=1)  then redirect 
and you can also use javascript redirect if header is not working

Answer (score -1):

1. Look at the closing "?>"-Tab. header will generate a html-header, but is a php-function and should be inside the ?php ?> bracket.
2. Consider using html5 input validation - saves some code and server roundtrips to let the browser do the validation
3. Omit the closing "?>" altogether. Its not necessary and can lead to hard to see errors when there is content - even blanks - after the "?>"
4. Consider using the filter_input function with appropriate parameters to access $_POST and set your variables.